# How to register a custom function for labelCallbacks for an existing entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I learned that in EntityBase the label method gets called to determine the label for an entity, for instance when it is rendered via the entity reference module as label.

Now, for specific node types I want to alter that label. In the module apparently a callback (alter?) gets called:

```
  public function label() {
    $label = NULL;
    $entity_type = $this->getEntityType();
    if (($label_callback = $entity_type->getLabelCallback()) && is_callable($label_callback)) {
      $label = call_user_func($label_callback, $this);
    }
    elseif (($label_key = $entity_type->getKey('label')) && isset($this->{$label_key})) {
      $label = $this->{$label_key};
    }
    return $label;
  }
```

How to register my own function for `$entity_type->getLabelCallback()`?

Comment: The lingo can be confusing at times. A *node type* is a bundle, such as `article` or `page`, therefore it's a *subset/category* of a specific entity type, not an entity type in itself, such as `user` or `node`. Perhaps you misunderstood? What are you trying to achieve? I am not sure if it's possible to specify different label callbacks for different node bundles.

Comment: @Beebee thanks, im basically having this problem: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284674/how-to-show-a-field-value-instead-of-the-node-title-for-nodes-displayed-though-a/284684#284684

Comment: I’m almost certain entity label callbacks have been deprecated in favour of the `label` method - I’d advise against using them. If you need different label logic per bundle, subclass `Node` and replace the class for the entity type via `hook_entity_type_build`

Comment: @Alex how are you displaying your referenced nodes? Perhaps you could just do something through the display manager (see Hudri's answer on your other Q) or something with a simple hook like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87079/5284 - you just need to set a condition to check the node type.